# webview linkclicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement, uiwebview, webview

I have a webview loading a website with a html form. When the user has entered their login credentials and push submit-button the user is sent to a new view controller. I want to stop this from happening IF the user enters the wrong credentials. If the wrong credentials are entered the website adress remains the same. Can I somehow say:

```
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavgiationTypeLinkClicked) {

if (url remains the same == alert view saying wrong credentials was entered.  

if (url changes - perform segue to new view controller?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your controller implement `UIWebViewDelegate`. When you do that, a bunch of callbacks will be called at different phases of the web request. The one you probably want to implement is this one:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Be sure to use mainDocumentURL, because any iframes on your form page will
    // also trigger this callback
    NSString *completedurl = webView.request mainDocumentURL.absoluteString;        
    // Let's assume you have your form url in the string property self.formurl
    if ([completedurl isEqualToString:self.formurl]) {
        // Display your alert view saying that the credentials were incorrect
    } else {
        // Perform segue to next controller
    }
```

The whole solution is **a bit scary** though, because any other error page or whatever would
trick your app to believe that the user was successfully logged on. A better approach might 
be to check the html contents of the webview for some significant string that the
successful-login-page contains. You can get the html body by calling:

```
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Yet another approach is to look for a cookie in the webview that confirms the login.

**Or even better, use a native login form, submit the login request with native code, using
AFNetworking or the standard http SDK methods, and check the response for success.**

Comment: Thanks! I will try your first answer, and If I don´t succeed I will try to find a success string - although I have don´t think there is one.

Comment: How could I do the if - if the successed login contains a significant string?

Comment: `NSString *htmlstring = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];`and the check if a substring exists using `if ([htmlstring rangeOfString:@"Logged in as"].location != NSNotFound)` Substitute the substring with something in your html that determines that the user is logged in.

Comment: It seems like the site doesnt contain any strings like that, instead, the user being allowed to go to the site is the login success. I´ve also looked for cookies but the cookies before and after login are the same - only the values of the cookies change. So my last resort is to try the standard SDK methods. I have no knowledge of that though.